# NodeJS request not giving any response in AWS Lambda

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using NodeJS request module to pass a JSON request to a URL and generate a JSON response from it. I tried this code and it generates a valid response. I am pasting the link for a StackOverflow question I asked for the same.

[NodeJS Request returning an empty array inside a JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205081/nodejs-request-returning-an-empty-array-inside-a-json-response)

However, when I utilize the same logic in AWS Lambda, there is no response at all from the module. Since there is no response at all, I cannot understand what the problem is.

This is the handling function for the AWS Lambda with Alexa as a trigger.

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request');

var accountNumberRequest = {};
var balanceResponse = {};
const url = "https://ibluatapig.indusind.com/app/uat/balinq/AccountEnquiry?client_id=6867b781-9b21-45c5-9c55-948f7cd1a33f&client_secret=hP3yB3hM2oH4pH4hM1kV3uY8vR3qV7jY8cF6bG2sF5jX8lT1vN";
var bal = {};
exports.handler = function (event,context) {
    try{
        console.log("Try Started");
        var req = event.request;
        console.log("Request Generated");
        if(req.type === "LaunchRequest") {
            console.log("Launch Request! Calling handleLaunchRequest");
            handleLaunchRequest(context);
        } else if(req.type === "IntentRequest") {
            console.log("IntentRequest");
            let options = {};
            console.log(0);
            if(req.intent.name === "BalanceIntent") {
            console.log("Balance Intent");
                //Got the account number from Alexa request
                let accNo = req.intent.slots.AccountNumber.value;
                console.log(accNo);
                accountNumberRequest = {
                    "AERequest":{
                        "serviceType":"BE",
                        "deviceId":"Test",
                        "accountId":accNo
                        }
                };
                console.log(accountNumberRequest);
                console.log("Calling NodeJS.Request");
                request({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    json: true,
                    header: {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: accountNumberRequest
                    }, 
                    function(error, response,body){
                        if(!error && response.statusCode === 200){
                            console.log(body.AEResponse.AcctBal[1].BalAmt);
                        } else {
                            //options.speechText = `The account <say-as interepret-as = "digits">${accNo}</say-as> does not exist`;
                            console.log("error: "+error);
                            console.log("response.statusCode"+response.statusCode);
                            console.log("response.statusText"+response.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                );
                console.log("Balance Response should be assigned by now");
                console.log(bal);


                /* if(accountNumbers.hasOwnProperty(accNo)) {
                    var balance = accountNumbers[accNo];
                    accountExists = true;
                }
                if(accountExists == true){
                    options.speechText = `The balance of account number <say-as interpret-as = "digits">${accNo}</say-as> is <say-as interpret-as = "cardinal">${balance}</say-as>`;
                } else {
                    options.speechText = `The account <say-as interepret-as = "digits">${accNo}</say-as> does not exist`;
                }*/
                context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
            }
        } else if(req.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
            //Code here
        } else {
            throw("Unknown Intent Type");
        }

    } catch(e){
        context.fail("Exception "+e);
    }
};
function getBalance(){
    //Code to parse the JSON response and extract values from the response.
    }

function handleLaunchRequest(context){
//Code for handling launch requests    }

function buildResponse(options){
    //Code for generating response
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you run the code? What do you see when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: What are you getting in AWS Lambda logs? Check cloudwatch. As you are calling another webservice from that, it might be getting terminated due to timeout (default: 3 seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem...

```
// You're sending an asynchronous HTTP request here.
request();
// But you sent the response here without waiting for the above request to finish.
context.succeed();
```

Basically, you're executing `context.succeed()` before `request()` finishes. So you're basically ending your Lambda invocation without the response from that HTTP request.

To fix your code, put the `context.succeed()` ***inside*** the callback that you pass to the `request()` call.

P.S.

You should be using `callback` instead of the deprecated `context.succeed()`/`context.fail()` API.